# Asserting specific xml tag from a document with Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, assert

I want to create a groovy script that will assert if a document or xml file contains a tag that contains also a specific value. I think I can define the file like this:

```
String fileContents = new File('/path/to/file').getText('UTF-8')
```

But I have struggle how to define the assertion. Lets say that this xml file that I want to check should contain a tag that is named `<ApplicationID>` with value `12345`. How can I verify that `<ApplicationID>12345</ApplicationID>` is contained in the specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the file as raw text, as:

```
assert new File('somefile').text.contains('<ApplicationID>12345</ApplicationID>')
```

or, parse the XML and specify the location in the XML for the data you want to check on.

```
Given:
    new File("somefile.xml").text = 
     '<someXml><someTag><ApplicationID>12345</ApplicationID></someTag></someXml>'

Then:
    assert new XmlSlurper()
     .parseText(new File("somefile.xml").text)
     ."someTag"."ApplicationID".text() == "12345"
```